# Storing and emailing HTML from database from WYSIWYG editor with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, encoding, xss, content-type

Im dealing with a bit of a problem. I have a WYSIWYG editor saving its data to a column in my database. Unfortunately the data is being stripped from the tags, so it looks something similiar to this:

```
 'Hello&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;'
```

Although theres no problem initiliazing this data into the WYSIWYG editor once again, but when i e-mail the data it recognizes the tags as text rather than HTML.

This is how i send:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
...
$this->email->send();
```

When the email is received it is as if the client ignores the HTML tags.

The content-type in the email which is received

```
Content-Type:   multipart/alternative; boundary=B_ALT_507c2c67f1aa7
```

Comment: Have you tried `$body = html_entity_decode($body);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending, run the body part of the email through [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$body = html_entity_decode($body);
```

It will replace entities like `&lt` `&gt` with their applicable characters like `<` `>`.

Comment: I noticed that when i save some of the HTML it has a tendency to cut some tags off and pretty much slice alot of text. Is CodeIgniter doing something to the HTML tags when saving?

Comment: Actually i noticed it cuts off at additional tags and commas.

Comment: Try debugging by writing something like `print_r($body);die();` before `$this->email->send();`, what will be the output in the html source? Is it being cut off as well?

Comment: I might have explained it wrong. When i create make commas and such inside of the WYSIWYG textarea and save it to the database column, it cuts off text from that area and down. So unfortunately something goes wrong when i am updating the row by simply using `set_value`. Does CodeIgniter attempt to strip anything when processing data in the model?

Comment: Yes, it does escape some characters to avoid SQL injection, it can be turned off by using `$this->db->set()` with an extra parameter or by writing your own insert/update using `$this->db->query();`. In any case, see your database field values in phpMyAdmin or other alternative database tool.

Comment: I can see that the text is actually cut off. Does `set_value` do this? I cannot find any information concerning that..

Comment: are you sure it's `set_value()`? It's the function from form helper that outputs data as can be seen here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html